# UriTemplate Parser interpret wildcards

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have uriTemplate like this

```
/{repository}/{id}/action/{methodName}/**
```

org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.util.UriUtils uses org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate to get variables in findMappingVariable method

UriTemplate.Parser build pattern to this value

```
\Q/\E(.*)\Q/\E(.*)\Q/action/\E(.*)\Q/**\E
```

why not to this?

```
\\Q/\\E(.*)\\Q/\\E(.*)\\Q/action/\\E(.*)\\Q/\\E(.*)\\Q\\E
```

Because of this feature I have empty map there

```
Map<String, String> variables = new org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate(mapping).match(lookupPath);
```

for this lookupPath

```
 /educationDistrict/308/action/resetAddressesForYear/1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `**` segments are allowed in URI templates. In that case, what would you expect when getting the path variables if several segments are matched by the `**` part?

Note that if you're trying to build templates in order to make REST calls, you should check RestTemplate and UriComponentsBuilder ([see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-resttemplate)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `UriTEmplate` that matches a regual expression, you can use it `{:}`  For example,

`/test-service/test-endpoint/countries/1/cities/2`

`/test-service/test-endpoint/people/5/adults/6`

can be matches with `UriTemplate` **respectively**.

`/test-service/test-endpoint/countries/{id}/cities/{id}`

`/test-service/test-endpoint/people/{id}/adults/{id}`

If you want to match **both**

`/test-service/test-endpoint/{:.*}`

[image]

Here are links

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.html#matches-java.lang.String-

[URI template needs to match with variable value that is a set of folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671292/uri-template-needs-to-match-with-variable-value-that-is-a-set-of-folders)